# How to search on complex fields in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Consider the following model, where `Address` has nested property of `City`

```
{
  "HotelId": "1",
  "HotelName": "Secret Point Motel",
  "Description": "Ideally located on the main commercial artery of the city in the heart of New York.",
  "Tags": ["Free wifi", "on-site parking", "indoor pool", "continental breakfast"],
  "Address": {
    "StreetAddress": "677 5th Ave",
    "City": "New York",
    "StateProvince": "NY"
  },
  "Rooms": [
    {
      "Description": "Budget Room, 1 Queen Bed (Cityside)",
      "RoomNumber": 1105,
      "BaseRate": 96.99,
    },
    {
      "Description": "Deluxe Room, 2 Double Beds (City View)",
      "Type": "Deluxe Room",
      "BaseRate": 150.99,
    }
    . . .
  ]
}
```

The model is indexed in Azure Cognitive Search as the following, where the `Address` is set as `Edm.ComplexType`

```
{
  "name": "hotels",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "HotelId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "filterable": true },
    { "name": "HotelName", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false },
    { "name": "Description", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "analyzer": "en.lucene" },
    { "name": "Address", "type": "Edm.ComplexType",
      "fields": [
        { "name": "StreetAddress", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false, "searchable": true },
        { "name": "City", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true },
        { "name": "StateProvince", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": true }
      ]
    },
    { "name": "Rooms", "type": "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)",
      "fields": [
        { "name": "Description", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "analyzer": "en.lucene" },
        { "name": "Type", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true },
        { "name": "BaseRate", "type": "Edm.Double", "filterable": true, "facetable": true }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I am trying to search on the data for `City` equals New York using the following queries, but none of them works

```
city eq 'new york' // return no result
address/city eq 'new york' // return error The property 'address/city' does not exist
address.city eq 'new york' // return error The property 'address.city' does not exist
```

So then how to search on `Edm.ComplexType` filed in Azure Cognitive Search?

N.B: I am using Azure Dotnet SDK (10.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is to define the OData expression in `$filter` clause. If you were using REST API, your $filter clause would be:

```
Address/City eq 'New York'
```

The reason your code is failing is because the actual field path is `Address/City` whereas you are specifying it as `address/city`. Once you use the proper field names, your code should work just fine.